# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined bitcoinjs-lib

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

## Summary

Angular application builds successfully using `ng serve -o`
but I get errors in the chrome console.

I don't even have to call the method, it breaks before anything is called.

It breaks in the `makeTransaction()` function.

## Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at inherits (inherits_browser.js:5)
    at Object.../../../../../../node_modules/hash-base/index.js (index.js:23)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Object.../../../../../../node_modules/md5.js/index.js (index.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Object.../../../../../../node_modules/create-hash/browser.js (browser.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Object.../../../../../../node_modules/bitcoinjs-lib/node_modules/bip32/src/crypto.js (crypto.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Object.../../../../../../node_modules/bitcoinjs-lib/node_modules/bip32/src/bip32.js (bip32.js:3)
```

I've tried deleting the node-modules folder and running >npm install,
I've tried importing the pakage in the app.module.ts file but I get another error.

### data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as bitcoin from 'bitcoinjs-lib';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private network: any) {
    network = bitcoin.networks.testnet;
  }

  // Make transaction
  makeTransaction() {
    // Network specification
    const test = this.network;
}
```